How to determine the last modification time of the quickfix list?
I'm using:

The quickfix list window (to go through vimgrep result)
The location list window (to go through the error CocDiagnostics output)
The CtrlSF buffer (to go through the result of the :CtrlSF command from the CtrlSF plugin)

I would like to use the same keyboard shortcuts ]q, [q to navigate them.
I would like to redirect the keyboard shortcuts to the correct list navigation operations:

cnext, cprevious
lnext, lprevious
call ctrlsf#NextMatch(1), call ctrlsf#NextMatch(0)

In order to use the correct API I would like to determine which list has been populated last.
For the CtrlSF buffer I could use:
strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S", undotree(bufnr('%')).entries[-1].time)

But how to determine the last time the quickfix list or the location list have been filled?
I have tried:
strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S', getbufinfo(bufnr('%'))[0].lastused)

But it gives the last time the quickfix list or localtion list has been used (including only visited) and not edited or filled.

Would it be fair to call this the “last modification time” (emphasis mine)? I thought you wanted to diff the current and previous lists from the title

@D.BenKnoble Thanks for the suggestion. The title reflect better the actual question.
